# What's the meaning of "after" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm reading the following passage, and I'm confused about a part of it:

> ORIGEN; Now if the Lord could neither receive increase or decrease, what is this that Mary speaks of, My soul doth magnify the Lord? But if I consider that the Lord our Savior is the image of the invisible God, and that the soul is created according to His image, so as to be an image of an image, then I shall see plainly, **that as after the manner of those who are accustomed to paint images**, each one of us forming his soul after the image of Christ, makes it great or little, base or noble, after the likeness of the original so when I have made my soul great in thought, word, and deed, the image of God is made great, and the Lord Himself whose image it is, is magnified in my soul.
>
> [Catena Aurea on Luke, Chapter 1, Lecture 14.](https://aquinas.cc/la/en/%7ECaLuke.C1.L14)

Could someone paraphrase "**that as after the manner of those who are accustomed to paint images**"?

I'm confused about how "**as after the**" is to be understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a somewhat old-fashioned and now rare construction. The phrase:

> after the manner of those who are accustomed to paint images
> ".
> simply means "In the way that painters (or other artists) do". "After the manner of X" means "in the way that X works (or acts). One sense of "after" in art or literary criticism is "in the style of" or "imitating".

For example:

> "A Field of Lilys" (after Van Gogh)

Means that the painting is in the style of Vincent van Gogh.